# True fullscreen browser display

Tags: macos, safari, fullscreen, firefox

I confess I'm not a regular Mac user so apologies in advance if this is a stupid question.

I'm building a web page to be displayed (offline) as a projection on a wall. On the Windows PC, running Firefox in full screen mode (F11) gives me exactly the desired effect -- no toolbars or other distractions, just the web page filling the entire display.

Over on the Mac (v10.8.5) I've tried getting this effect in both Safari and Firefox. On Firefox I got stuck because I couldn't figure out how to hide the navigation bar (yes, I do feel stupid).

On Safari I can manually get rid of all the toolbars but even after that I'm still stuck with a bright white line across the top of the display where the menu bar would appear were I to drag the mouse up there.

I'm after a solution that doesn't require installing add-ons or other software (this isn't my machine) and that is as low-hassle as possible (non-techy folks will be setting it up each day). I might get away with something that can be run off a USB stick if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a lot easier in OSX El Capitan now because there is an option to not show the toolbar in fullscreen mode.

However, in Lion, I believe you can still do this:

1. Enter Full Screen mode
2. Secondary click on the grey area above the address bar and choose "Hide Toolbar" in the Contextual Menu displayed.

That should get you what you need.

Comment: I did try that (in Firefox), but unfortunately "Hide Toolbars" did exactly nothing. Most disappointing!

Comment: Sorry - I should have stated this was for Safari.  I must have misunderstood that you meant in Firefox.

Comment: Oh gotcha -- yes I did manage to hide all the toolbars in Safari, but was stuck with the row of white pixels at the top of the screen where the OS menu bar is hiding.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two way.

1. Opera

In addition to Fullscreen Mode, Opera has a Presentation Mode. It is a fullscreen window without any UI.

2. Classic Theme Restorer & Tree Style Tab Addons.

CTR allows you to hide toolbars, while TST autoshow/hide tabbar when the cursor is near an edge of the screen.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't meet the basic requirements of the OP's question, which specifically requests: 'I''m after a solution that doesn't require installing add-ons or other software (this isn't my machine) "